# Как работает раскрутка стека в C++?

Tags: c++, исключения, стек

Никак не могу понять последний этап раскрутки стека.

Допустим, есть функции `А`, `B`, `C`. Вызываются они также: `A->B->C`.
В функции `C` выбрасывается исключение, запускается некая функция рантайма по поиску обработчика сначала во фрейме функции `С`, если не находит обработчик исключения, содержимое фрейма `С` затирается, потом ищет в `B` и стирает его фрейм в стеке, а обработчик находится в функции `A`, обработчику которой нужно передать управление.

Как затирает свой фрейм функция рантайма, которая раскручивает стек после того, как найдет нужный обработчик?

Comment: Ну, формально это может быть и не вызов функции. А как именно выполнять раскрутку стека, в стандарте не указано, каждый компилятор может делать это по-своему...

Comment: В любом случае должен быть код который выполняет поиск по .gcc_except_table, только как он передает управление в обработчик исключения и корректно завершается?

Comment: imho реально ничего не трется, просто в конце  регистры изменяются так, чтобы sp и fp соответствовали фрейму A (где находится обработчик), а в pc заносится адрес обработчика. (после этого, естественно, активация функции раскрутки просто исчезает. В общем, основная идея та же, что и в longjmp)

Answer (score 3):

Каждый компилятор делает это по своему. Например `g++` создаёт отдельный код, который вызывает просто деструктор всех переменных в данной функции. И это продолжится пока не натыкается на обработку `catch`. Если стек вызовов закончился данный процесс просто заканчивает свою работу.
Например код

```cpp
string fun(string & a,string & b){
  return a + b ;
}
```

имеет скрытый обработчик исключения такой :

```cpp
void _Unwind_fun(void){
  b . ~ string () ;
  a . ~ string () ;
  _Unwind_Resume ( ) ;
}
```

`_Unwind_Resume` ничего не возвращает и раскручивает стек дальше.

Никто ничего не затирает, вызываются деструкторы и просто стек вызовов опускается для обработки кода дальше.